# partition manager в KDE. как изменить точку монтирования?

Tags: linux, kde, mount

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как пользоваться Partition Manager в KDE? Есть окно для изменения точки монтирования, но как сохранить изменения я в упор не понимаю? Кнопки просто напросто отсутствуют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновить программу надо. При порте KDE4->KF5 я незаметил и пропустил Ok/Cancel кнопки. Исправлено в новой версии (3.0.x).

Answer (score 0):

в [документации](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-sysadmin/partitionmanager/partitionmanager.pdf) написано:

> **Partition → Edit Mount Point**
>   Opens a dialog to edit the mount point and the mount options.
>   This command is only enabled if a partition unmounted.

«эта команда доступна только если раздел (на самом деле файловая система, конечно) отмонтирован».

для отмонтирования надо воспользоваться другим пунктом меню (или кнопкой):

> **Partition → Mount/Unmount**
>   Mounts or umounts a partition: This command mounts or unmounts the selected partition,
>   depending on its current state.
>   This command is only enabled if a partition is selected that can be mounted or unmounted.
>   If the operating system does not know a mount point for the partition you can not mount
>   it from KDE Partition Manager.

Comment: диск не примонтирован. если диск примонтирован вообще нет возможности открыть окно "точка монтирования"

Comment: так в чём тогда проблема-то? нажмите кнопку «выбрать» и укажите другой каталог для монтирования.

Comment: ну выбрал. А дальше? дальше, очевидно, должна быть кнопка "ок", нажатие на которую приведет к изменению настройки. На скриншоте видно, что никаких кнопок нет. Можно просто закрыть окно. В этом случае, очевидно, ничего не поменяется.

Comment: т.е., вы нажимаете кнопку «выбрать», и в диалоге тоже отстутствует кнопка «ок/применить/ещё-что-нибудь»?

Comment: Кнопка "выбрать" открывает системный диалог выбора каталога. Т.е. просто выбрать путь. Окей, путь я выбрал. Затем нужно все настройки монтирования сохранить  .... только вот это невозможно сделать. Просто нет кнопки "применить/сохранить/ок". Это похоже на какую то адскую недоработку.